# Having trouble fetching XML through React-Native

Tags: xml, react-native, parsing, fetch, expo

Been struggling for a while now trying to fetch data from xml url. This is the first time I've ever tried it and can't seem to figure it out.
Any data I'm missing I can provide.

I've tried to fetch events from facebook but had more issues doing that so now I'm trying to fetch data from stubwire.

I'm not sure how to directly parse from xml to return data. I understand that there are many lib for this but I think I've been going at it too long and could use some fresh eyes.

```
import React from 'react';
import {  
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'native-base';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

var eventList = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
    '<html lang="en">\n' +
    '<head>\n' +
    '    <style>\n' +
    '        .rhFormSection{margin-bottom:10px}.panel{margin-bottom:20px;border-width:0;color:#333}.panel-flat>.panel-heading+.panel-body{padding-top:0}.rhFormSection .panel-body{padding:10px}.panel-body{position:relative;padding:20px}.row{margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px}.rhInlineGroup{margin-bottom:0;min-height:38px;position:relative!important}.form-group{margin-bottom:20px;position:relative}.full-width{width:100%}.input-group{position:relative;display:table;border-collapse:separate}.dateGroup{width:50px;background-color:#d3d3d3;height:100%;float:left}.appDay1,.appDay2{width:100%;text-align:center;float:left}.appDay1{background:#008b8b;color:#fff!important}.appDay2{height:35px;line-height:35px;font-weight:700;font-size:12pt}.contentGroup{float:left;margin-left:10px;width:80%}.appDate1,.appDate2,.appTitle{float:left;width:100%}.appTitle{height:20px;font-weight:700}\n' +
    '    </style>\n' +
    '</head>\n' +
    '<body>\n' +
    '<div class="panel panel-flat rhSectionPanel rhFormSection " data-section="appointments">\n' +
    '    <div class="panel-body">\n' +
    '        <div class="row">\n' +
    '            @[LOADING]\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '    </div>\n' +
    '</div>\n' +
    '</body>\n' +
    '</html>';
var html = '';

export default class EventsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Events',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      this.state = {
        loading: false,
        data: [],
        page: 1,
        seed: 1,
        error: null,
        refreshing: false,
        webViewHeight: 100,  
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `http://website.api.stubwire.com/?website=ChopShopLive-App&version=8`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
        })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: 1,
        seed: this.state.seed + 1,
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  _updateWebViewHeight = (event) => {
    this.setState({webViewHeight: parseInt(event.jsEvaluationValue)});
}

  openLink = (url) => {
    Linking.openURL(url)
    .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}

  saveEvent = (data) => {
    var arrNames = []
    var monthNames = [
      "January", 
      "February", 
      "March",
      "April", 
      "May", 
      "June", 
      "July",
      "August", 
      "September", 
      "October",
      "November", 
      "December"
    ];
    var weekday = new Array(7);
      weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
      weekday[1] = "Monday";
      weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
      weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
      weekday[4] = "Thursday";
      weekday[5] = "Friday";
      weekday[6] = "Saturday";

      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          let event = data[i]
          let eventId = events.event.id
          let name = events.event.name
          arrNames.push(name)
          let place = events.event.venue.name
          let street = events.event.venue.address
          let city = events.event.venue.city
          let state = events.event.venue.state
          let zip = events.event.venue.zip
          let url = events.event.venue.url
          let location = street + ', ' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip
          let description = typeof events.event.shortDescription !== 'undefined' ? events.event.shortDescription : ''
          let ticket_uri = typeof events.event.urls.buyNowLink !== 'undefined' ? events.event.urls.buyNowLink : ''
          let startDate = events.event.dateTime
          startDate = startDate.replace(startDate.slice(-5), ".000Z");
          let ageDesc = typeof events.event.ageDescription !== 'undefined' ? events.event.ageDescription : null

          let alarms = [{
              date: startDate,
              structuredLocation: {
                  title: events.event.name,
                  // proximity: 'enter',
                  // radius: 500,
                  coords: {
                      latitude: place.location.latitude,
                      longitude: place.location.longitude
                  }
              }
          }]

          let settings = {
            url: ticket_uri, 
            location: location, 
            notes: description, 
            description: description, 
            startDate: startDate, 
            ageDesc: ageDesc, 
            allDay: false, 
            alarms: alarms
          }

          if(i == 0)
          {
              settings.needDeleteAllEvent = true
          }
          var dt = new Date(startDate);
          var shortMonth = monthNames[dt.getMonth()];
          var shortMonthSub = shortMonth.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
          var fullDateString = weekday[dt.getDay()] + ', ' + shortMonth + ' ' + dt.getDate() + ', ' + dt.getFullYear();
          var ageDescString = '';
          if(ageDesc !== null)
          {
              var dt2 = new Date(ageDesc);
              ageDescString = ' to ' + dt2.getHours() + ':' + dt2.getMinutes();
          }
          var fullHourString = 'from ' + dt.getHours() + ':' + dt.getMinutes() + ageDescString;
          var nameString = name;
          if(nameString.length > 35)
          {
              nameString = nameString.substring(0, 35) + '...';
          }
          try {
              RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent(name, settings)

              html += '<div class="form-group rhInlineGroup col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 5px; cursor: pointer;">' +
                  '                <div class="input-group full-width">' +
                  '                    <div class="dateGroup"><span class="appDay1"> '+shortMonthSub+' </span> <span class="appDay2"> '+dt.getDate()+' </span></div>' +
                  '                    <div class="contentGroup"><span class="appTitle"> ' + nameString + ' </span> <span class="appDate1">'+fullDateString+'</span><span class="appDate2">' + fullHourString + '</span></div>' +
                  '                </div>' +
                  '            </div>';

          }
          catch (error) {
          }
      }
      eventList = eventList.replace('@[LOADING]', html);
  }

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20, borderTopWidth: 1, borderColor: "#CED0CE"}}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ events }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              title={`${events.event.name}`}
              subtitle={events.event.dateTime}
              avatar={{ uri: events.event.images.eventImageURLSmall }}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={events => events.event.urls.buyNowLink}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

To fetch data from url and show on ios.

Result:
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `EventsScreen`.

Below is my package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I removed some of the fetch from fb code and converted xml into json, simple fix.